# Swapping columns and deleting column SQL BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

This is the Unclosed identifier literal at my "from" how do i add both the query you sent and this query together with the select. Also I forgot to mention I want the update query before the select query i want it to update first then do whatever its in the select

```js
SELECT *,
                      TIMESTAMP_DIFF(start_date, expected_start_date, MINUTE) AS Difference_Start_Time,
                      TIMESTAMP_DIFF(end_date, expected_end_date, MINUTE)     AS Difference_End_Time,

                      CASE
                          WHEN TIMESTAMP_DIFF(start_date, expected_start_date, MINUTE) <= 0 THEN TRUE
                          WHEN TIMESTAMP_DIFF(start_date, expected_start_date, MINUTE) > 0 THEN FALSE
                          END AS Started_On_Time,
                      CASE
                          WHEN TIMESTAMP_DIFF(end_date, expected_end_date, MINUTE) <= 0 THEN TRUE
                          WHEN TIMESTAMP_DIFF(end_date, expected_end_date, MINUTE) > 0 THEN FALSE
                          END AS end_date_tracker,
                   CASE
                          WHEN end_date is null then 'FAILED'
                          ELSE 'COMPLETED'
                          END AS status_tracker
               FROM `np-inventory-planning-thd.IPP_SLA.sla_table,

update `np-inventory-planning-thd.IPP_SLA.test_sla_table`
set expected_start_date = timestamp(CONCAT( EXTRACT(DATE FROM TIMESTAMP(start_date)),' '
,EXTRACT(TIME FROM TIMESTAMP(expected_start_date)) )), expected_end_date = timestamp(CONCAT( EXTRACT(DATE FROM TIMESTAMP(end_date)),' '
,EXTRACT(TIME FROM TIMESTAMP(expected_end_date)) ))
where 1=1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below.

```
update table_name
set expected_start_date = timestamp(result)
where 1=1;


ALTER TABLE table_name DROP COLUMN IF EXISTS result;
```

Comment: Ok also, result is a column created from as "as" will it still be able to read. Like its not a column premade it, in my query I have it made from an "as"

Comment: It will not work here as statement. Provide the query, I'll regenerate based on your input.

Basically, the formula/derivation used for result field need to be replace here in [timestamp(result)]

Comment: Ok sure I will provide my query. This is a rough query so you can change it as you please.

Comment: SELECT
 *,
 CONCAT( EXTRACT(DATE
   FROM
   TIMESTAMP(start_date)),' ',EXTRACT(TIME
  FROM
    TIMESTAMP(expected_start_date)) ) as result
FROM `np-inventory-planning-thd.IPP_SLA.test_sla_table`

                                                                                                                            
update `np-inventory-planning-thd.IPP_SLA.test_sla_table`
set expected_start_date = result
where expected_start_date=result;

Comment: This is my query stackoverflow kind of messed up the format is this fine and do able to you?

Comment: I update my post above too if this is badly formatted

Comment: update np-inventory-planning-thd.IPP_SLA.test_sla_table 
set expected_start_date = timestamp(CONCAT( EXTRACT(DATE FROM TIMESTAMP(start_date)),' ',EXTRACT(TIME FROM TIMESTAMP(expected_start_date)) )) 
where 1=1;

Comment: just updated my post^

Comment: See the second reply with formatted codes.

Comment: thank you is it ok if i can give you one follow up just for formatting purposes

Comment: I have this sql query and I am getting an error at my "from" saying its an Unclosed identifier literal

Comment: i will update it to my post if you are willing to help

Comment: sure. I'll try.

Comment: also I forgot to mention I want the update query before the select query i want it to update first then do whatever its in the select

Comment: Yes. That is given in latest reply. First Update will executed. then the select statement.

Answer (score 0):

See the code based on new feed.

```
update np-inventory-planning-thd.IPP_SLA.test_sla_table 
set expected_start_date = timestamp(CONCAT( EXTRACT(DATE FROM TIMESTAMP(start_date)),' ',EXTRACT(TIME FROM TIMESTAMP(expected_start_date)) )) 
where 1=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
update `np-inventory-planning-thd.IPP_SLA.test_sla_table`
set expected_start_date = timestamp(CONCAT( EXTRACT(DATE FROM TIMESTAMP(start_date)),' '
,EXTRACT(TIME FROM TIMESTAMP(expected_start_date)) )), 
expected_end_date = timestamp(CONCAT( EXTRACT(DATE FROM TIMESTAMP(end_date)),' '
,EXTRACT(TIME FROM TIMESTAMP(expected_end_date)) ))
where 1=1;

SELECT *,  TIMESTAMP_DIFF(start_date, expected_start_date, MINUTE) AS Difference_Start_Time, 

TIMESTAMP_DIFF(end_date, expected_end_date, MINUTE)  AS Difference_End_Time,

CASE WHEN TIMESTAMP_DIFF(start_date, expected_start_date, MINUTE) <= 0 THEN TRUE WHEN TIMESTAMP_DIFF(start_date, expected_start_date, MINUTE) > 0 THEN FALSE END AS Started_On_Time,

CASE WHEN TIMESTAMP_DIFF(end_date, expected_end_date, MINUTE) <= 0 THEN TRUE WHEN TIMESTAMP_DIFF(end_date, expected_end_date, MINUTE) > 0 THEN FALSE END AS end_date_tracker,

CASE WHEN end_date is null then 'FAILED' ELSE 'COMPLETED' END AS status_tracker 
FROM `np-inventory-planning-thd.IPP_SLA.sla_table`;
```

Comment: By the way I did not dislike these posts lol idk who did. Also its saying the last from is an Unclosed identifier literal

Comment: I have edited and resolved that issue. try now.

Comment: Hi, so when I put your query you have here when I run it it only updates it. It does not do anything with the select statement. Is there suppose to be something around the select statement for that also to run?

Comment: It updates "expected_start_date" and "expected_end_date" fields. Once the updates done. You are selecting records to view the result.. right.